# How can I slide in a background-image transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've got a list setup. What I want to do is when you hover over the list item, The following background image appears.

[image: Hover Image]

What I'd like to do is add an effect, As the background image is a form of gradient, I'd like it to swipe from the left to the right.

I've not had much luck finding a resource for this on google.

My current CSS is :

```
.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  background: url(../img/menu-hover-bg.png) no-repeat left;
}
.menu-item a {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}
```

I've also made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2v25ppz/3/) of what I have at the moment.

Comment: What do you want to swipe? Only the background image (https://jsfiddle.net/t2v25ppz/18/)? Or the whole menu item (https://jsfiddle.net/t2v25ppz/20/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a transition on the `background-size` property, which seems to have the desired effect:

```
.menu-item {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMwI7.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px 100%;
}
```

See this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2v25ppz/22/

Comment: pay attention as with this code you are changing both sizes of the background :) and thus you created a top/left to bottom/right transition ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, didn't catch my eye in the quick transition! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can play with background-size like this:

```css
#sidebar {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  background: #21203d;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMwI7.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-size: 200px 100%;
}

.menu-item a {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul id="menu" class="main-menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Our Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Fixtures</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can also easily recreate this background without the use of image and you can have a more complex animation:

```css
#sidebar {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  background: #21203d;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(#f13c4a,#f13c4a),
  linear-gradient(to right,black,transparent);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size:  5px 0%,0 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-size: 4px 100%,200px 100%;
}

.menu-item a {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul id="menu" class="main-menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Our Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Fixtures</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```